Apple falling from boat mast
To better understand how gravity and movement works, a common question is to ask where an apple would land if dropped from the top of a mast on a moving boat (let's assume a boat with a motor but with a mast, and no wind blowing apart from the relative speed of the boat, and a constant speed, let's say 50km/h, it's a fast boat).
People often mistakenly answer it would land on the rear of the boat, because the boat is still advancing forward while the apple is falling straight down.
So it is explained that there is a conservation of movement, and the apple was moving at the same speed as the boat, and hence it would land at the base of the mast, and it is often added that it's the same case as if you jump on a moving train, you don't end up at the rear of the train, but instead land where you were before.
However it seems to me that those 2 examples are not the same. On a train, the compartment is closed, so the air is trapped and also moves with the train. With the boat case, there is no close environment, so as soon as it gets dropped, it loses contact with the boat and stops being accelerated by the boat motors (that counteract the water/air slowing it down, so that it maintains a constant speed), so starts being slowed down by the air around it.
Assuming a 20m mast, I think it takes roughly 2s for the apple to reach the boat, and I'd say that in 2s, the air has ample time to slow the apple enough so that it doesn't fall on the bottom of the mast, but rather closer to the rear of the boat. Am I wrong? How far would the apple land (if there's not enough numerical values, feel free to take any reasonable choice)?

"conservation of movement" should read, "conservation of momentum." The momentum (vector) of an object is the product of its mass (scalar) and its velocity (vector.) In an inertial reference frame, the momentum of an object does not change except when momentum is transferred between the object and something else by force acting between the object and the something else. The total momentum of a closed system does not ever change.

And if you want to deal with a real boat you've also going to have to account for wave action. Honestly, I suspect this is one that can end up pretty much anywhere, in front of the boat, behind, off to the side, depending on exactly what happens.

Please note that (even under idealized conditions when there's no wind or air drag), this is only true if the boat/train is not accelerating (uniform motion is required - constant speed in a straight line).

You are not wrong of course.  The examples are supposed to be idealized examples where we ignore air friction.

Thanks. I added a second question : how far would it land then ?

That depends on details of the air speed, the mass of the apple, the cross section of the apple, etc.  In general, air friction is very complicated to model.

Just take general assumptions, for example for the mass of the apple you can use 100g. I'm not looking for a precise answer, and I'm sure there are ways to roughly estimate if it would land closer to 10cm or 1m or 10m

I really don't know.  I haven't worked much with modeling air resistance.

As soon as you start modeling air resistance @elilu, you're no longer considering the nature of gravity and now are considering aerodynamics. Gravity has the same effect, atmosphere or no atmosphere; the effect the atmosphere has is a different field of physics.

so it's really impossible to tell if the apple would fall 1nm or 1mm or 1m or 1km away from the mast ? It's okay if it's a different field of physics, or if approximations are needed, I just want a rough estimation of the answer.

It’s about 3m or so

thanks ! Can you please explain how you arrive to this conclusion ?

@elilu To elaborate on what travis and controlgroup are saying, the question you ask is orders of magnitude more complicated than you think. Aerodynamics (fluid dynamics in general, really) is one of the most complicated fields of physics--some even consider it to be more difficult than quantum mechanics or general relativity, two famously difficult fields. In many cases, the equation defining the movement is actually impossible to solve in closed form, and you have to resort to numerical approximation, using methods like finite element analysis.

Remember that we had to wait for astronauts to go to the moon so they could demonstrate that a feather and a hammer drop at the same rate when there's no air resistance.

@Barmar We didn't have to wait for that: we had large vacuum chambers before then. That was purely symbolic.

Actually, I've found the best way to tease aerodynamic considerations out of this is to ask what would happen if you dropped an apple and a feather. If the feather moves further towards the back than the apple then what's happening to the apple?

@elilu pretty sure that Kenshin just put down a number. I suggest you post a new question and explicitely write down all assumptions you make (including cross sections, temperature etc.). Then give your ansatz and say where you're stuck. This is where we can help you.


Assuming a 20m mast, I think it takes roughly 2s for the apple to reach the boat, and I'd say that in 2s, the air has ample time to slow the apple enough so that it doesn't fall on the bottom of the mast, but rather closer to the rear of the boat. Am I wrong? How far would the apple land (if there's not enough numerical values, feel free to take any reasonable choice)

What really matters is the force applied to the apple by the perceived wind.  Your question has a hidden assumption that the boat is travelling in an area with a wind speed of 0 relative to the water, so the apple experiences a wind equivalent to the speed of the boat in the opposite direction of it's movement.  There might actually be a wind to either side that would move the apple sideways or even a strong tailwind that would make the apple land closer to the FRONT of the ship.
Using a drag calculator and using 4 inches for the size of an apple, approximating cross-section as a circle, using a wind speed of 30mph, and using google's result of 0.36 for an apple's drag coefficient I get 0.3241N for the force of the wind on the apple.  Using 5oz for the mass of the apple and another calculator I get an acceleration of the apple of 2.3 m/s.  But after one second that will lower the apple's speed relative to the wind by about 5mph and therefore the force, and the apple will then be accelerated by the wind at about 1.6 m/s.
So given the wind is moving at 30mph relative to the boat, the apple will land about 3.5 meters from the point on the boat it would fall on naturally if the boat were moving at the same speed as the wind relative to the water and the air seemed calm on the deck.
Note that this is highly dependent on speed.   Back in the 1800s a more common speed would be about 10mph and the calculation shows that would only move the apple about 0.5 meters before it hit the deck.   If the ship had a 20mph tailwind that would be 0.5 meters in front of the point where it was dropped.


However it seems to me that those 2 examples are not the same. On a train, the compartment is closed, so the air is trapped and also moves with the train. With the boat case, there is no close environment, so as soon as it gets dropped, it loses contact with the boat and stops being accelerated by the boat motors (that counteract the water/air slowing it down, so that it maintains a constant speed), so starts being slowed down by the air around it.

As other answers have already pointed out, in physics 101 we are discussing an ideal situation, where the air drag is neglected. Once it is taken into account, the two situations become different, for the reasons described in the Q. This is why people often err in answering the boat question - because the answer based on no air drag contradicts our experience.
This situation could be modeled, assuming for simplicity drag described by Stoke's law:
$$
m\frac{d\mathbf{v}(t)}{dt}=-\gamma\mathbf{v}(t) +m\mathbf{g},
$$
which in projections on the horizontal and vertical axes gives us:
$$
m\frac{dv_x(t)}{dt}=-\gamma v_x(t),\\
m\frac{dv_y(t)}{dt}=-\gamma v_y(t) - mg
$$
These are linear differential equations that are easy to solve (things would be a bit more difficult with more realistic quadratic drag.)
Related: Why do rain drops fall with a constant velocity?
